# Detectar pulsación de un encabezado de una tabla en JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Tengo una tabla que muestra el contenido de una lista la cual tiene un escuchador que hace que cada vez que cambia su contenido hace que se actualice a su vez la tabla. Quiero detectar el intento de ordenar la tabla cuando se pulsa en el encabezado antes de que se ejecute el escuchador de la lista pero no lo consigo. He probado creando un manejador en las columnas de la tabla de esta forma:

```
columna.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
           public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
               // intento de ordenar columna...
           } 
        });
```

pero no funciona. O dicho de otra forma: quiero que al ordenar la tabla no se dispare el escuchador de la lista mostrada por la tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes registrar el evento a la tabla que contiene las columnas y cuando se genere el evento leer el tipo de ordenamiento de la columna de interés.

```
tabla.setOnSort((event) -> {
        System.out.println("Tipo de Ordenamiento: "+colummna.getSortType().name());
    });
```

Estas son las respuestas:

- Tipo de Ordenamiento: ASCENDING
- Tipo de Ordenamiento: DESCENDING